# Error in Logistic Regression for Factors in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to do logistic regression by using the code:

```
model <- glm (Participation ~ Gender + Race + Ethnicity + Education + Comorbidities + WLProgram + LoseWeight + EverLoseWeight + PastYearLW + Age + BMI, data = LogisticData, family = binomial)
```

summary(model)

I keep getting the error:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Upon checking the forums I checked to see which variables were factors:

```
str(LogisticData)
'data.frame':   994 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ outcome       : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ Gender        : Factor w/ 3 levels "Male","Female",..: 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 
$ Race          : Factor w/ 3 levels "White","Black",..: 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 
$ Ethnicity     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Hispanic/Latino",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
$ Education     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Below Bachelors",..: 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 
$ Comorbidities : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...
$ WLProgram     : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": NA 1 2 2 1 1 1 NA 1 1 ...
$ LoseWeight    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
$ PastYearLW    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": NA 2 1 1 1 2 1 NA 1 1 ...
$ EverLoseWeight: Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
$ Age           : int  29 35 69 32 21 45 40 62 59 58 ...
$ Participation : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 ...
$ BMI           : num  25.7 33.8 26.4 32.3 27.5 ...
```

All factors appear to have 2 or more levels.

I also tried to omit NA's which still gave me this error.

I want all variables in the regression, and can't figure out why it won't run.

When performing :

```
newdata <- droplevels(na.omit(LogisticData))
> str(newdata)
'data.frame':   840 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ outcome       : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Gender        : Factor w/ 3 levels "Male","Female",..: 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 
 $ Race          : Factor w/ 3 levels "White","Black",..: 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 3 
 $ Ethnicity     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Hispanic/Latino",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
 $ Education     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Below Bachelors",..: 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 
 $ Comorbidities : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ WLProgram     : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ LoseWeight    : Factor w/ 1 level "Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PastYearLW    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ EverLoseWeight: Factor w/ 1 level "Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Age           : int  35 69 32 21 45 40 59 58 23 32 ...
 $ Participation : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ BMI           : num  33.8 26.4 32.3 27.5 45.4 ...
 - attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  Named int [1:154] 1 8 13 14 21 24 25 
46 55 58 ...
 .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:154] "1" "8" "13" "14" ...
```

This doesn't make sense to me because you can see in the first str(Logisitic Data) that there is obviously 2 levels in EverLoseWeight as you can see both the Yes and the No and the 1 and 2? How do I fix this anomaly?

Comment: Check if the levels are the same in `newdata <- droplevels(na.omit(LogisticData))`

Comment: At a glance, `Ethnicity` looks suspicious. It is possible for factors to have two levels but with only a single level present. Consider `x = as.factor(c(1,1,1)); levels(x) = c(1, 2)`.

Comment: @akrun The levels are not the same, but this doesnt make sense to me. Please View additional post.

Comment: There can be unused levels i.e. levels that are not present

Comment: I updated to explain a bit more. But I get the logic now- if the observations that correlate to that variable are dropped then it would provide one level. My mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your update, it looks like you have at least two possibilities.

1: Remove the factors that are left with only a single level after removing the NAs (i.e. `LoseWeight` and `EverLoseWeight`).

2: Treat the NAs as an extra level. Something along the lines of

```
a = as.factor(c(1,1,NA,2))
b = as.factor(c(1,1,2,1))

# 0 is an unused factor level for a
x = data.frame(a, b)
levels(x$a) = c(levels(x$a), 0)
x$a[is.na(x$a)] = 0
```

But this might not deal with any singularity issues that also resulted in having single-level factors.

Comment: Yeah, I did an iteration with both, but wasnt sure how to close the post without an "Answer".

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `summary` on your raw data and make sure that all of the levels have values. I would put this in a comment, but I don't have the reputation points :(